# Margin auto calculated in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a problem. 
I want to achive this:
[image]

I'm using LinearLayout. Size of LinearLayout and ChildViews are const. Problem is, that results of my work looks this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/answersLayout"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bck_number_red"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/boxOfRecycleViewer" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorOperator"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorOperator"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorOperator"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using `ConstraintLayout` to contain your LinearLayout. You should be easily doing this with `ConstraintLayout`.

If you use the `LinearLayout` to be able to give background then you can use `Space` with weight in between views.

```
<Space
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using `ConstrainLayout` to pack three layouts and set horizontal chain style as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstContainer"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorOperator"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/secondContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondContainer"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorOperator"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/thirdContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/firstContainer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/thirdContainer"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorOperator"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/secondContainer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to have 5 `Views`: 3 `FrameLayouts` (your 3 `FrameLayout`s) and 2 white `View`s that go in the middle. In this way:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/answersLayout"
    android:weightSum="3"    <!-- This is useless, if you don't define weight parameter in each child -->
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bck_number_red"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/boxOfRecycleViewer" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorOperator"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#FFF"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorOperator"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#FFF"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorOperator"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But I think that working with weights is better, and allows the Layout to be scalable depending on devices:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/answersLayout"
    android:weightSum="3.5"    <!-- Now it has significance -->
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bck_number_red"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/boxOfRecycleViewer" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/colorOperator"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFF"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/colorOperator"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFF"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/colorOperator"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, I advise you to use `ConstraintLayout`.